# How do I prevent race conditions in Upstart 'starting on' scripts?

Tags: upstart, init

I am working on a package that needs two Upstart jobs: one that launches a daemon, and another that launches a supporting daemon *if* the configuration file requires it. The logic to determine if the supporting daemon should be launched involves processing the configuration file with `sed` and friends, which causes problems with Upstart's daemonization detection (Upstart has no way to distinguish PIDs), so `expect fork` and `expect daemon` aren't useful. Unfortunately, this means Upstart detects the first invocation of `sed` as the first PID, and immediately starts the main job, before the supporting daemon is fully initialized. This frequently leads to the premature termination of the main job, due to an improperly configured environment.

Is there any way to prevent Upstart from starting the main job too soon in this scenario?

`expect stop` looks like it's close to what I need, but I don't see a way to raise that signal without terminating one of the daemons, neither of which generate the SIGSTOP signal on their own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this ended up being in the [Upstart documentation](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#daemon-behaviour):

> Create a post-start section that performs some check and only returns once the service is "ready".

Answer (score 1):

Simple - use a `pre-start` stanza to perform all your `sed` checking. If the `pre-start` determines that the supporting daemon should not be started, have it call simply `stop` (which forces Upstart to ***not*** continue starting the job). There is an example of this in the Upstart Cookbook here:

http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#pre-start

Note that Upstart only performs PID tracking for the `exec` and `script` stanzas (in other words the "main" part of the job) - PIDs for `pre-start`, `post-stop` *et al* are not tracked. See http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#expect

Comment: +1 for pointing out `stop` (I wasn't aware of that command), but I was wanting to delay the start, not prevent it entirely.